# Not able to run ASP.NET core app as a windows service

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services, webserver, http.sys

I have an ASP.NET CORE project with 3.1 version. I am using HTTP.SYS to host this project. There are some static files in wwwroot folder which are being served in this program. Here's how my **startup.cs** looks.

```csharp
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddMvc().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(o =>
        {
             o.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;
             o.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
        })
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(o => o.SerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset)
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
            
        services.Configure<HttpSysOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:44385/");
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            });
         });
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
            
        app.UseFileServer();
        app.UseRouting();
            
        app.UseCors(o => o.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => 
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And my **program.cs** looks like this:

```csharp
public class Program
{
     
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
  }
  public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
      Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
          .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
          {
             webBuilder.UseHttpSys();
             webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
          }).UseWindowsService();
}
```

Now with this code I am able to create a windows service and run it, but I only see the Hello World message when I hit the url. No static page is displayed when the service is running. I assume I'm doing something wrong here. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> app.UseFileServer();

Call app.UseFileServer to enable the serving of static files and the default file, the Directory browsing isn't enabled, so when you access the static files, it will return the 404 error.

To solve this issue, we could enable the Directory Browsing, Try to change your code as below (By default the static file is stored in the `wwwroot` folder):

```
        app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
        { 
            RequestPath = "/StaticFiles", //assign the request path.
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
        });
```

Then, the test screenshot as below:

[image]

More detail information, check the [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: this might work. What I tried was simply adding the wwwroot folder in the bin folder where all other dll were getting generated. Then from that path's exe I created a windows service and everything worked fine. The problem here was that it couldn't find static files while going through the exe as told by program.